# how to handle unique identifier values during SSIS import

Tags: oledb, ssis, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to to import an excel file with a unique identifier column into SQL server but SSIS is giving me a lot of trouble.

I can get the unique identifier values from excel into the OLE DB Destination component but i can't get them into SQL Server table.

I get the error message below on trying to insert the unique identifier.

NOTE: column CreatedBy is of type uniqueidentifier in the destination SQL server table.

> There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[CreatedBy] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you try this:

```
(DT_GUID)("{"+(DT_WSTR,36)[CreatedBy]+"}")
```

because your initial string doesn't contain any brackets you need to add them before converting to GUID.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a Derived Column with the following transformation

```
REPLACE(REPLACE((DT_WSTR,50)[CreatedBy], "{", ""), "}", "")
```

and map the new derived column to the output destination.

have fun!

Comment: ok, almost works. However, derived column [CreatedBy] is returning NULLS while the non-derived one has the GUID Values. Any idea why the derived column is returning NULLS?

Comment: increase the nvarchar length from 50 to 70:  REPLACE(REPLACE((DT_WSTR,70)[CreatedBy], "{", ""), "}", "") and tell me if this works

Comment: Ok, it was returning null because i had set the Derived Column error output to ignore failure. If i set it to fail on component it does not even go past the Derived Column transformation. I have also tried the data conversion transformation and its also failing to transform the values into a valid GUID. The string i'm trying to transform is this "9AC394FB-0D17-4B0B-862B-F5E448458EB6"? Does it need any more special handling?

Comment: Here is what is working for me: (DT_GUID)("{"+(DT_WSTR,36)[CreatedBy]+"}"). I recommend you try this.