# Value does not fall within the range in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm struggling a lot with an SSIS package I’m trying to execute.
I have a OLE DB SOURCE which is populated using a SQL Command, and it was working just fine, the preview works fine.

When I try to add a new column in the SELECT query, which is of type `uniqueidentifier`, then I have this error message:

> Value does not fall within the range in SSIS package

I am using a OLE DB SOURCE and an OLE DB DESTINATION. I'm using SQL Server, and the OLE DB SOURCE is the one failing with this error:

> Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[LegalAddressCode] on the non-error output has no corresponding output column on the error output.

Comment: Can you describe the data flow that you have set up? What components are you using, and which ones are failing?

Comment: @AHiggins i am using a OLE DB SOURCE and an OLE DB DESTINATION, i'm using SQL Server, and the OLE DB SOURCE is the one failing

Comment: With this error: Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[LegalAddressCode] on the non-error output has no corresponding output column on the error output.

Comment: But i do have a corresponding output

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating the OLE DB SOURCE component?

Comment: @AHiggins yes yes i did, several times, when i remove this column i add, it all works fine, i don't understand why...

Comment: Have you checked the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513691/how-to-handle-unique-identifier-values-during-ssis-import)?

Comment: @AHiggins, yes, but it's not my case, this is very frustrating

Comment: Can you post the full text of your SELECT statement (before & after)?

Comment: @AHiggins, done, the difference is betweeb asterisks ** **

Comment: Add a new data flow, call it "Test". Add an OLE DB Source component. Use the following query `SELECT le.AddressCode AS LegalAddressCode FROM ALB_BR_LegalEntity AS le` Add a Derived Column Task. Right click in the background and select Execute Task. Does it run to completion or does it generate the error?

Comment: @billinkc i did this and no error, it worked fine..

Comment: By virtue of you being able to add that column into an empty data flow, we can conclude the error is not with the data source. You can replace the single column select in the test data flow with your full query and it will work, right? Hit control alt O in the ssis editor. This brings up the output window, assuming default key mappings. Rerun your falling data flow task and there should be 3 to 5 lines of output that start with ERROR.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493090/how-to-fix-ssis-value-does-not-fall-within-expected-range/38445843#38445843 That might help

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are now misaligned. You are now trying to insert a GUID, 16 bytes long, into a variable that is smaller. Check the mapping in the OLE task.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, well i'm trying to insert a GUID into a GUID column, should i change it to something else?

Comment: Check the number of columns you are getting back and if everything's maps as you think they do. It sounds like a classic, very common, off by one error.

Comment: Everything maps like i think they should... well, thanks for the help

Comment: I have this problem when I work to IMAGE Data. It dose not work.